# How to convert back the ACSII to a number

Tags: char, ascii

I'm trying to validate the user input. So whenever the user input a character, it display a message. But whenever i tried to display the number again, after validation, on the screen, it display the ASCII number instead of the value input. I don't know how to convert it back to its original number. So this is my code:

```
char ch;
double num;
num=cin.get();
ch = static_cast <char> (num);
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
    cout << num << "this is a positive number";
else
    cout << num << "this is not a number";
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you expect a double as an input and not just get the char ?

Comment: cause i'm checking whether a double input is a character or a number

Comment: Why do you cout the num and not the ch, which is the character that you check ?

Comment: because if i'm cout the ch, it will display a character but not the number. What I'm trying to do here is to check the user input, if it's a number, cout that number, if it's a character, cout saying the input is not a number.

Comment: If I input the character '0' it will pass your if condition and in the cout it will display: 0this is a positive number. If I cin "c" it will display: cthis is not a number

Comment: Yes, that's what i am intending to do and also cout that number that was input. If i'm using that code without the cout << num part, just cout << "this is positive number", it's somehow correct but when I cout << num, it's not the number that the user input.

Comment: Ok, let;s go to ASCII. Every character has a number behind it. For example '1'=49, '2'=50 so you can't expect the char to be the same as the ASCII code. Here is a ASCII table http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif . Also you want to show the user what his/her input is. so it's logical to show the inputed value and not the converted value